# $scope variable do not respond to the onClick function of angular chart

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, chart.js, angular-chart

I have a chart in the page. When one click in the chart, the onClick function will be called and it will know which category of the chart has been clicked by user. I created a div to show `$scope.cateClicked`. However, the display value of `$scope.cateClicked` do not change in the div, while in console, I can see this value has been changed by the function indeed.

See my example here: http://codepen.io/lyzy0906/pen/ggWqpJ

The div and the canvas:

```
<div>You clicked {{cateClicked}}</div>
<canvas class="chart chart-pie" chart-click="onClick" chart-data="data" chart-labels="labels" chart-colors="color" chart-options="option"></canvas>
```

The onClick function:

```
$scope.onClick = function(elements, evt) {
    $scope.cateClicked = elements[0]._model.label;
    $scope.tabIndex = 1;
    console.log($scope.cateClicked);
};
```

How can I make the DIV to display the value of $scope.cateClicked after one has clicked in the chart? Thanks.

Comment: You need to initiate digest cycle. Use `$scope.apply` or better use `$timeout`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need a `$scope.$apply();` as the last thing in the `onClick` function:

```
$scope.onClick = function(elements, evt) {
  $scope.cateClicked = elements[0]._model.label;
  console.log($scope.cateClicked);
  $scope.$apply();
 };
```

It looks like the bindings are not updated by the chart-click in the same way they would in ng-click.

Answer (score 0):

Adding $timeout kicks in the digest cycle. This works!

```
   angular
      .module('StarterApp', ['ngMaterial', 'chart.js'])
      .controller('AppCtrl', function ($scope, $timeout) {
        $scope.cateClicked = "?";
        $scope.color = ["#378A58", "#3FBF4E", "#83DF1F", "#AAD466"];
        $scope.labels = ["A", "B", "C", "D"];
        $scope.data = [1, 2, 3, 4];
        $scope.option = {legend: {position: 'right', display: true}};
        $scope.onClick = function(elements, evt) {

          $timeout(function(){
            $scope.cateClicked = elements[0]._model.label;
          $scope.tabIndex = 0;
          }, 0)

         };

    });
```